# Display explicit points on x axis for Density plots(ggplot2) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have plotted a density plot using ggplot2 and as a next step I would like to explicitly highlight specific points(outliers) on x-axis. Below is my graph as far now:
[image: Density Plot]

Below was my code to generate the same.:

```
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=df$Infection_Risk)) + geom_density() + xlab("\n Infection 
  Risk") + ylab("Density \n")
```

Now, I want to show points c(7.7 7.6 7.8 1.3 1.3 1.4) explicitly on x axis with a different shape

Can someone please give an hint on this on what my next step should be?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider plotting those using `geom_point` or `geom_jitter` (which adds some positioning noise to help distinguish overlapping points).

Here with fake data:

```
df <- tibble( Infection_Risk = rnorm(100, 4.5, 2))

outliers <- tibble(x = c(7.7, 7.6, 7.8, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4), y = 0)

ggplot(df,aes(x=Infection_Risk)) + geom_density() + xlab("\n Infection 
  Risk") + ylab("Density \n") +
  geom_jitter(data = outliers, aes(x,y), height = 0.01)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why tibble is better than data frames ?

Comment: data.frame would be just as good here. There are some minor advantages to tibbles that make them my go-to equivalent, but fine not to use.  https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/tibble.html

Comment: Thanks, Btw can you please tell how to change the shape of points ? For example. If the points to be in diamond or square?

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html     geom_jitter(data = outliers, aes(x,y), height = 0.01, shape = 23)  ... or shape = 22)